# Start Activity with Quick Tile, Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I currently have a MainActivity (QR Code reader) and a QuickTile, I'm trying to link both (if I click on the tile, it starts the QR Code reader).

The MainActivity is classic:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var codeScanner: CodeScanner

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // ALL THE CODE FOR THE QR CODE
    }
}
```

and the AndroidManifest with the service:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyTileService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="QR"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_border_clear_24"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">
    <intent-filter>
         <action
             android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Now the TileService, I don't know what to do on the onClick(), last thing I tried was to open a second activity:

```
class MyTileService : TileService() {
    override fun onTileAdded() {
        super.onTileAdded()

        // Update state
        qsTile.state = Tile.STATE_INACTIVE

        // Update looks
        qsTile.updateTile()
    }
    override fun onClick() {
        super.onClick()

        val myIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivityAndCollapse(myIntent)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a QuickTile? And what is TileService?

Comment: Only add an `android-studio` tag if you have problems with the Android Studio IDE. I think you have not.